# Laptop mute button LED

Tags: kubuntu, kde5, 23.04, mute

I am using Kubuntu 23.04, and I cannot seem to get the mute button LED (F6) to work. Mute works, the LED does not. My audio card is ALC236, HP laptop.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-20-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
Memory: 13.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics
Manufacturer: HP
Product Name: HP Laptop 15-ef0xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug fix for the HP 655 keyboard mute LEDs:

- [Speaker / Audio/Mic mute LED don't work on a HP platform](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2011379)