# Audio-mute led not working: how to check if software or hardware problem?

Tags: keyboard

Ubuntu 20.04 on a Thinkpad X1. Simple problem: the audio-muted led, on the audio-mute fn-key, is suddenly not working, although the audio-mute key is working normally (audio-mute, not mic-mute). I would just like to check if this is a hardware or software issue. How can I check this?

Some Q&A on askUbuntu about this are quite old (e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/138217/1519798), whose answer doesn't work in my case). Others, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466258/laptop-mute-button-led), have never been answered (TBH I doubt this will be answered either...).